# mysql match with regex multi word

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to make a research in a mysql database with several word machting word OR subword

for instance if I search for "ata" I want to obtain "data" and "database"
if I search for "ata" and "get" I want to obtain "database is getting"

For the moment I use 2 times LIKE function:

```
SELECT col FROM mytable WHERE col LIKE "%ata%"
```

and then

```
SELECT col FROM mytable WHERE col LIKE "%get%"
```

if work but I think there is a more efficient way to that.

I tried:

```
SELECT col FROM mytable WHERE MATCH (col) AGAINST (concat('%','ata get','%') IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

but it does not work.

If there a solution using MACH AGAINST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use `and` in your original query?

```
SELECT col
FROM mytable
WHERE col LIKE "%ata%" and col like col LIKE "%get%"
```

Or, you can combine them into one expression if you care about the order of the matches:

```
select col
from mytable
where col like '%ata%get%'
```